# How to select the particular row for delete operation using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have main checkbox and a checkbox against each of the row, If i select on main checkbox then, all the items present is getting checked, but i am not able to get the entire row for deleting in console.
And what ever row i click also i must get that item in console.

HTML:

```
<a id="lnk_Condition" (click)="deleteConditionDetails()" style="padding-left: 15px">Delete
</a>
<p-table #dt [columns]="tableHeaders" [value]="ccdList" [lazy]="true" [paginator]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadLazy($event)"
  [totalRecords]="totalcount" [rows]="10">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr role="row">
      <th width="30">
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" (change)="selectAll()" #ccdListViewChild>
      </th>
      <th width="90">Date Added
      </th>
      <th width="300">Description
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
      <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowData.selected" (change)="checkIfAllSelected();"></td>
      <td>{{rowData.DateAdded}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.Description}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

TS:

```
selectAll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.ccdList.length; i++) {
    this.ccdList[i].selected = this.selectedAll;
  }
}

checkIfAllSelected() {
  this.selectedAll = this.ccdList.every(function (item: any) {
    return item.selected == true;
  })
}

deleteConditionDetails() {

}
```

Comment: please provide the whole code so we can help, or implement it here to make it easier https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgotmi

Comment: @maha thanks for response, ya i will create

Comment: @maha, please have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdrsnd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: yes much better, can you now please tell me what exactly you need because the question itself is not clear

Comment: @maha: If i click on one check box and click on delete, i must get that entire row in console

Comment: so you just wanted the checked box to be printed?

Comment: ya, that is my requirement

Comment: give me one moment

Comment: @maha, if i delete only one is getting deleted even though i select full list.

Comment: try this :    deleteConditionDetails() { 
    let i=0;
    for(i=0;i<this.ccdList.length;i++) {
      if(this.ccdList[i].selected){
          console.log(this.ccdList[i]);
          this.ccdList.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first change the `Delete` to a `button` just to make it easier :

```
<button (click)="deleteConditionDetails()"> Delete </button>
```

and then in the function implement this:

```
   deleteConditionDetails() {
    let i=0;
    for(i=0;i<this.ccdList.length;i++) {
      if(this.ccdList[i].selected)
          console.log(this.ccdList[i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: can u pls look into this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928975/how-to-get-the-total-count-of-items-of-a-screen-in-sidebar-of-different-componen